# Android uninstalling an application and checking the result

Tags: android

I want to delete an application from the device using the startActivityForResult()

I have tried this but always getting 0 as requestCode even for the cancel button

is it possible?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: That activity may not be setting result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to delete an application from the device

You can delete an android application from your applicatio code by calling

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:com.your.packagename"));
l.startActivity(intent);
```

This will prompt an alert to user before deleting the application. User need to confirm if.